# Jenkins: files/folders selection from subversion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for a jenkins plugin that would allow selection of file(s)/folder(s) for a parameterized build.

The purpose is to be able to select different tests to execute, each test being defined as a .xml file in a svn repo.

eg of repo structure:

`tests/business/cars/buy.xml

tests/business/cars/sell.xml

tests/system/core/stuff.xml`

Comment: I am not aware of any plugin that does that, but how about using your scripting language of choice to render the Jenkins job configuration?

Comment: what do you mean? create the plugin myself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if these quite get at what you're looking for, but I found the following two possibilities:

***[Test In Progress](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+In+Progress+Plugin)*** which, based on their GitHub information, should allow you to run tests based on pattern matching and view the progress as they run.

***[RQM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RQM+Plugin)*** is an IBM tool made to allow you to run specific test cases in a test plan that have a custom property that you configured and provide at test execution time.

**edit:**

I just found ***[Multi Module Test Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi+Module+Tests+Publisher)***, which may be a little closer to what you're looking for.  It acts as a replacement for the normal junit plugin and allows you to group junit tests into suites and view statistics on each separately.

Comment: @domi I've edited my answer to include Multi Module Test Publisher, which I think is actually much closer to what you are looking for.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not at all what I was looking for. My point was to make a parameterized build, where the test could be selected from a subversion repository. This cannot be achieved with current svn plugin with a lot of tests nested in different folders.

What I wanted is, some kind of directory structure explorer which would allow selecting tests or folders.

rough examle: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/previews/unit_test_explorer.png